# How can I deploy/push the SUB-DIRECTORY OF a subdirectory of my git repo to Heroku?

Tags: git, heroku, deployment, web-deployment, git-push

This is my Repo structure...

Root repo>reactnodejsapp>backend (and) reactapp.

I want to push my "backend" directory which is 2 layers inside from my root repo.  How can I do that?

I know how to push the subdirectory to Heroku with

`git subtree push --prefix reactnodejsapp heroku master`

And

`git push heroku 'git subtree split --prefix reactnodejsapp branch':master --force`

But it pushes the subdirectory.  How can I push the SUBDIRECTORY of the SUBDIRECTORY????

I tried these commands...

`git subtree push --prefix reactnodejsapp/backend heroku master`

`git subtree push --prefix reactnodejsapp\/backend heroku master`

`git subtree push --prefix reactnodejsapp\backend heroku master`

`git push heroku 'git subtree split --prefix reactnodejsapp/backend branch':master --force`

`git push heroku 'git subtree split --prefix reactnodejsapp\backend branch':master --force`

`git push heroku 'git subtree split --prefix reactnodejsapp\/backend branch':master --force`

But in all cases it says

> 'reactnodejsappbackend' does not exist

The terminal thinks "reactnodejsapp/backend" is the name of one subdirectory.  How can I let it know that backend is inside reactnodejsapp.

I also tried all of the previous commands with and without quotes.

Help, please...

Comment: I had this problem once and the second command you mentioned worked after adding `=` after the `--prefix` flag, so you would do  
`git push heroku 'git subtree split --prefix=reactnodejsapp/backend branch':master --force`.  
Lemme know if this works

Comment: @Himanshu Pant Had you the same problem?  Was your deployed directory 2 layers inside??  Because I tried it too,  but it does not work.  Same result..... Help please.  Was your situation same?

Comment: @Himanshu Pant I mean,  was your deployed directory a SUBDIRECTORY???  Or a SUBDIRECTORY of another SUBDIRECTORY???

Comment: Yeah, mine was 3 layers deep inside root, and this worked, we eventually switched to a cd workflow so we completely forgot about it. Our directory structure was like so.  
```  
(root)  
  --newCode  
    --src  
      --backend
```

Comment: we use the following [script](https://github.com/AkhileshNS/heroku-deploy) in our CD pipeline, sorry I couldn't be of much help.

Comment: @Himanshu Pant Thanks a lot!! You helped a lot friend!!! Really appreciate it!!!

Comment: When you get done, please post an answer, so we all become better.